# Getting a selected item in a List Control, changing subitems

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

How can I catch a click on an item, and then change all it's subitems states?

[image]

I know I can get the selected item with GetFirstSelectedItemPosition, but how do I use the SetItemState on the given position?

EDIT: I was basically looking for this: m_ListControl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT)

Answer (score 0):

Create a notification handler for the `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` notification. This handler will be called whenever a new item has been selected either using the mouse or the keyboard. If you particularly need to handle mouse clicks, create a notification handler for the `NM_CLICK` notification instead.

Both event handlers' `LPARAM` parameter points to a structure that contains a member called `iItem`. This is the index to the item just selected or clicked. Use this `iItem` as the first parameter to the `SetItemState` method.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get this items sub-items?

Comment: In the case of a click, the structure pointed to by LPARAM also has a member called iSubItem that you can use. If you want to enumerate all the sub items, call GetHeaderCtrl and then call its GetItemCount method. If you want to apply state to individual sub-items, then you will need to create an owner draw list control as this is not supported. You will find owner drawn list controls here - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/

Comment: But how come mine doesn't have a LPARAM, and instead has: OnLvnItemchangedList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)

Comment: I was talking about doing it in Win32. You're doing MFC and that is the same. Use the `pNMHDR` parameter by typecasting it to a `NMLISTVIEW` structure.